# CakePHP 3 display time of session timeout based on session configuration

Tags: cakephp

This is my session setting in app.php (CakePHP 3)

```
'Session' => [
    'cookie' => 'name',  
    'defaults' => 'database',    
    'timeout'=>'20',         
    'handler' => [         
        'engine' => 'DatabaseSession',
        'model' => 'A0'
     ]

],
```

Printing the current time to exipre of the session:

```
echo $this->request->session()->read('Config.time');
```

shows me a huge number, e.g. 1570704344

I have set the timeout to 20 minutes. Is there a mistake in my setting or I am showing the time to timeout incorrectly?

Comment: Seem like you didn't configure your session correctly. You can use chrome developer mode to see session expire value of your site.

Answer (score 0):

`1570704344` is a timestamp.

From CakePHP docs:

> Please note that php.ini's session.gc_maxlifetime must be equal to or greater than the largest Session['timeout'] in all served websites for it to have the desired effect.

And to read  the setting:

```
\Cake\Core\Configure::read('Session.timeout')
```

Comment: echo \Cake\Core\Configure::read('Session.timeout'); shows me '20'. I still do not understand what is wrong

Comment: What is the problem? Does the session not time out after 20 minutes?

Comment: I am trying to double check it now, because I had a feeling that it expires sooner several times. I am trying to measute it now.